# I am trying to save text extracted from all images into single .txt file but getting the following error AttributeError:

Tags: python, data-science, python-tesseract

```
#Code Entered
from PIL import Image
import pytesseract as pt
import os

def main(): 
    path ="C:\\Users\\folder1\\folder2"
    tempPath ="C:\\Users\\folder1\\newfolder"
    for imageName in os.listdir(path):
        inputPath = os.path.join(path, imageName)
        img = Image.open(inputPath)

        text = pt.image_to_string(img, lang ="eng")

        fullTempPath = os.path.join(tempPath, 'time_'+imageName+".txt") 
        print(text)

        file1 = open(fullTempPath, "w")         
        file1.write(text)
        file1.apend(text)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
`
```

#Error occured
   #AttributeError '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'apend'
   #Please help in savin the data in a single file

Answer (score 0):

Does it work if you change:

```
file1.apend(text)
```

to

```
file1.append(text)
```

?

Also, what is file1.append doing here? If you want to write some data to a file, you're probably best off with:

```
with open(fullTempPath, "w+") as f:
    f.write(text)
```

This will close the file after you're done writing.